# How to use mouseleave with if

Tags: c#

When checkbox checked ,  mouseleave-enter events be false, when unchecked mouseleave-enter events be true. How can I do them ? Sorry for my bad language

Comment: The event is always going to pop. Events aren't conditional. What you can do is, in the event handler, check if your checkboxes are checked or unchecked, then do something (or just leave the event handler) depending on your conditions.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @Icemanind, you have to add the business logic (i.e. the `if` condition pertinent to your case) into Mouse Enter/Leave event handler. For .NET C#/WPF `CheckBox` it could be implemented as shown in the following sample code snippet:

```
private void CheckBox_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chk = sender as CheckBox
    if((bool)chk.IsChecked)
    {
       // YOUR CODE HERE
    }
}

private void CheckBox_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chk = sender as CheckBox
    if((bool)chk.IsChecked)
    {
       // YOUR CODE HERE
    }
}
```

Also, you can combine these two event handlers into one if the logic for both Mouse Enter/Leave events is similar.
Hope this may help. Best regards,

Comment: I'm tryed but not working and not checkbox_mouseenter , be checkbox_Checked

Comment: You have to specify: are you using WPF of Win Form? The event handlers code snippet would be slightly different. Check the MSDN documentation pertinent to your case. Best regards,

Comment: I'm using WPF. Code not working.

Comment: Please show us your code and highlight the part which is not working. Regards,

Answer (score 0):

My codes. When checkbox checked mouseleave-enter true , When unchecked mouseleave-enter false.I'm edited codes can u look again ?

```
    private void CheckBox_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chk = sender as CheckBox;
        if ((bool)chk.IsChecked)
        {
            main1.Width = 740;
            main1.Height = 156;
        }
    }
```

`

Comment: Please clean-up your code and put it into your original Question. And don't forget to subscribe the particular CheckBox control to both events (use that += syntax). Regards,